# Method not found in tokens selection module

Tags: corda

- Corda: OS 4.3-RC01
- Tokens: 1.1-RC01
- Accounts: 1.0-RC-04

I have the following scenario:
1. Create `AccountInfo` using `CreateAccount` flow.
2. Request new key using `RequestKeyFlow`.
3. Wrap the key with `AnonymousParty`.
4. Create `EvolvableTokenType`.
5. Issue a certain amount of that token to a node.
6. Move the amount from the node to the account (which is hosted on a different node).

When I run the flow test for step #6, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.database.selector.DatabaseTokenSelection.generateMove(Ljava/util/UUID;Ljava/util/List;Lnet/corda/core/identity/AbstractParty;Lcom/r3/corda/lib/tokens/selection/TokenQueryBy;)Lkotlin/Pair;
at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.move.MoveTokensUtilitiesKt.addMoveFungibleTokens(MoveTokensUtilities.kt:102) ~[tokens-workflows-1.1-RC01.jar:?]
```

I've added this to my `MockNetwork`:

```
TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection")
```

And inside my flow (that calls `MoveFungibleToken` flow):

```
PartyAndAmount partyAndAmount = new PartyAndAmount(newKey, amount);
SignedTransaction moveTx = subFlow(new MoveFungibleTokens(Collections.singletonList(partyAndAmount)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify token SDK dependencies in your modules refer to the same version. If they do, try clearing your gradle cache. If i'm not mistaken, RC versions do not guarantee reproducible builds, i.e. multiple releases might be using the same version (think snapshots)

Comment: I did a restart and clean cache in Intellij and it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved after clearing Gradle cash.